# How many different hues, saturations and values are possible when converting RGB to HSV?

Tags: image-processing

If we specify a colour in the RGB space, there are $2^{24}$ different colours, as R, G and B are 8 bit numbers.

When a colour is converted to the HSV colour space (find the conversion formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) for example), **how many different values are possible for H, S and V?**

Obviously, the total number of colours is equal in both spaces, as the conversion is a bijection. But how is the information distributed over the three dimensions of the HSV space?

Answer (score 0):

The answer ist 118920. The 2^24 RGB values result in 118920 different hues, 19821 saturations, and 256 values. The last one is kind of obvious, but the first two were interesting. I wouldn't have expected the difference to be that big.

What is very interesting is the scatter plots of hue, saturation and values of the colours.

[scatter plots of hue, saturation a value of RGB colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSwG.png)

It turns out that there are very few distinct hue values for low saturations and values, which makes sense, because hue is not "important" for greys and dark colours.

What I found most astonishing were the patterns in the hue-saturation plot.

Anyway, that was an interesting and fun exercise.